# removing an item from an array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am learning React and I can't seem to figure out how to remove an item from an array. I have tried couple of ways but it either removes the entire array or more than one item in the array so I can't find any working solution. Here is my code:

App.js:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Education from './Education';

export default function App() {
  const [educationArray, setEducationArray] = useState([]);
  const handleDeleteEduItem =(id)=>{
  
    const eduArrayToSplice = [...educationArray]
    const newEduArray = eduArrayToSplice.splice(id, 1)
    
    setEducationArray(newEduArray)
    console.log(id)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <div className="edit-mode">
    <h4>Education</h4>
    <button onClick={()=>{setEducationArray([...educationArray, <Education id={educationArray.length} handleDeleteButton={handleDeleteEduItem}/>])}}>add new</button>
    {educationArray.map((eduItem, i)=><div className="eduItem" key={i}>{eduItem}</div>)}
       
     
    </div>
    </div>
      
  );
}
```

And the functional component:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';

function Education(props)

 {
       const [schoolName, setSchoolName] = useState('');
       const [major, setMajor] = useState('');
       const [studyFrom, setStudyFrom] = useState('')
       const [studyTo, setStudyTo] = useState('');
       const [degree, setDegree] = useState('');
       const [displayEducationSection, setEducationSection] = useState(false)
      
    

       const changeSchoolName = (e) => {
              setSchoolName(e.target.value);
            };
          
       const changeMajor = (e) => {
              setMajor(e.target.value);
            };
       const changeStudyFrom =(e)=> {
              setStudyFrom(e.target.value);
            };
       const changeStudyTo =(e)=> {
              setStudyTo(e.target.value)
            };
       const changeDegree =(e) => {
              setDegree(e.target.value);
            };
       const flipEducationSection =()=> {
              setEducationSection(!displayEducationSection)
            };
   

          
          
    return(
        <div className="education-section">
            {displayEducationSection ? 
            <div>
              <p>School Name: {schoolName}</p>
              <p>Major: {major}</p>
              <p>from: {studyFrom}</p>
              <p>to: {studyTo}</p> 
              <p>Degree: {degree}</p> 

            </div>
            :
            <form onSubmit={(e)=>e.preventDefault()} className="education-form">
            <label>
                   School Name:<input value={schoolName} onChange={changeSchoolName} />
            </label>
            <label>
                   Major:<input value={major} onChange={changeMajor} />
            </label>
            <label>
                   From:<input value={studyFrom} onChange={changeStudyFrom} />
            </label>
            <label>
                   To:<input value={studyTo} onChange={changeStudyTo} />
            </label>
            <label>
                   Degree:<input value={degree} onChange={changeDegree} />
            </label>

                
            </form>}
            <button onClick={flipEducationSection}>{displayEducationSection ? 'edit' : 'save'}</button>
            <button onClick={()=>props.handleDeleteButton(props.id)}>delete</button>
        </div>
    )

}



export default Education;
```

I've also used the following function to try to remove an item from the array, but it doesn't remove the clicked item but removes all items that come after it:

```
const handleDeleteEduItem =(id)=>{
  const newEduArray = educationArray.filter((item)=>educationArray[item] !== id)
  
  setEducationArray(newEduArray)
  console.log(educationArray)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't want to filter directly the state. What you could do instead is:

```
setEducationArray((cv) => cv.filter((e) => e.id !== id ))
```

This way you get to access the current value in your educationArray state (cv), and filter that to get all elements where the e.id is not equal to the id you have given to your id.

Edit:

To be fair, I'm not sure how your array eventually looks like. But if it was an array of objects, with each object having its own id. Then I would suggest the thing I wrote above.

Comment: Thanks. The array is an array of objects where each object has an id and a component, i.e. {comp: <Education />, id: 'unique id'}. For some reason, when I click on the button, the filter removes all array objects that come after the one where ids match. For instance, when I click on the second object in the array, it deletes object 2 and all the objects after it so all I have left is object one. That is not the behavior I was hoping for. I only need to remove object two and that's it, and I can't figure out why that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

you can not directly update the state with using same memory location.
you have to create new memory to updated array and then update the component state. you will see quickly changes on UI.

else this function will help you to remove single item from array.
you have to

> ensure that your id should be unique for each item.

const handleDeleteEduItem =(id)=>{

```
const eduArrayToSplice = [...educationArray.filter(item)=>item.id!==id)]   
setEducationArray(newEduArray)
console.log(id)
```

}

Comment: Thanks. Is the correct way to update state is by creating a new array before filtering? 'const arrayToFilter = [...educationArray]` ?

Comment: yes you are right this is the right way to create new array.